# How to remove only dtype: int64, from the list in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to the Python environment. I created a list which has column names, data value and it's frequency count(highest count). however, I am only interested in keeping the column name, date value, and the frequency in the output. this output may be a data frame, list or dictionary

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

I tried to use reset_index() or to_string(header=None) but it removed everything

```
df_vec = [(df.loc[:, x].value_counts().head(1)) for x in df.columns]

[160.0    1
 Name: Unnamed: 0, dtype: int64, 160.0    1
 Name: Site.No., dtype: int64, Wakuia Wai    2
 Name: Site.Name, dtype: int64, *    48
 Name: Site.Code, dtype: int64, New Ireland    24
 Name: District, dtype: int64, PNG    31
 Name: Island, dtype: int64, PNG    74
 Name: Country, dtype: int64, E    67
 Name: Technique, dtype: int64, igneous    48
 Name: Geology, dtype: int64, boulder    46
 Name: Topography, dtype: int64, cliffed    24
 Name: Location, dtype: int64, *    76
 Name: Proxhab.km., dtype: int64, AN    54
 Name: Language, dtype: int64, *    98
 Name: No.motif, dtype: int64, 0    98
 Name: Ca1, dtype: int64, 0    101
```

I need something like this (better to have this result in a dataframe)-

```
Name: Unnamed: 0 , 160.0 ,    1
Site.No. , Wakuia Wai,    2
Site.Name , * , 48
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do with `stack` rather than your original loop

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(1)
Out[205]: 
Keys    a    3
Reason  x    3
dtype: int64
```

---

Sample Data

```
  Reason Keys
0      x    a
1      y    a
2      z    a
3      y    b
4      z    b
5      x    c
6      w    d
7      x    d
8      w    d
```

Comment: Hi I made a slight change in your code like                                                                   
 df1 = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().groupby(level=1).head(1) . How can I keep only first record for each group ?

Comment: @ved_null_ ah , if that meet what you need , feel free to do so

Comment: but I need to extract out only data value with highest freq count for each column. At present, I am getting each data value with freq count for each column